# Atom core dumps in Ubuntu on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-14.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux, x-windows, atom-editor

I want to use an atom package which is unsupported on Windows... but here's the catch - I want to use it on Windows.

This is what I have done:

- [Enabled Bash and installed Ubuntu on Windows 10](http://www.laptopmag.com/articles/use-bash-shell-windows-10)
- [Installed Xming on Windows 10 to use graphical X Window System applications](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3055403/windows/windows-10s-bash-shell-can-run-graphical-linux-applications-with-this-trick.html)
- Installed gedit on Ubuntu and successfully used it `sudo apt-get gedit`
- [Installed Atom on Ubuntu](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/08/05/install-atom-text-editor-ubuntu-16-04/)
- [Installed libxss1 on Ubuntu to satisfy a missing dependency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547151/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libxss-so-1)

I've gotten so far just to fail now!

```
root@CHERNIKHOV:~# sudo atom
sudo: unable to resolve host CHERNIKHOV
root@CHERNIKHOV:~# /usr/bin/atom: line 119:   117 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
[117:0114/120453:FATAL:render_sandbox_host_linux.cc(40)] Check failed: 0 == shutdown(renderer_socket_, SHUT_RD). shutdown: Invalid argument
#0 0x000001e09b2e <unknown>
#1 0x000001e1f73b <unknown>
#2 0x000001e1fcfd <unknown>
#3 0x000002893352 <unknown>
#4 0x00000265e7f9 <unknown>
#5 0x000002664dbf <unknown>
#6 0x00000265de96 <unknown>
#7 0x000001204397 <unknown>
#8 0x000001202e70 <unknown>
#9 0x0000033a9803 main
#10 0x7f0ccb101f45 __libc_start_main
#11 0x000000575279 <unknown>
```

Ideas for a fix or next step in debugging are welcome.

EDIT: Some more debugging...

I created two Ubuntu 64 bit VMs in VirtualBox with default settings, networking set to bridged and installed Ubuntu Server 16.04.01 in one, Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.01 in the other. I installed atom and openssh-server on both. Atom starts up in Ubuntu desktop. When Using PuTTy and Xming to try to render Atom in Windows, however, the results are invariably bad. A simple X Windows application, xclock, works fine across SSH with Xming in both environments.

Ubuntu Server:

```
root@Farnum:~# atom
root@Farnum:~# /usr/bin/atom: line 119:  1506 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
atom --executed-from=/home/voidstar --pid=1493: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id:
```

Ubuntu Desktop:

```
root@Ylva:~# atom
root@Ylva:~# /usr/bin/atom: line 119:  7610 Aborted                 (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1

(atom:7610): IBUS-WARNING **: The owner of /home/voidstar/.config/ibus/bus is not root!
Home directory not accessible: Permission denied
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
atom --executed-from=/home/voidstar --pid=7597: ../../src/xcb_io.c:274: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
Failed to get crash dump id.
Report Id:
```

EDIT:
Using mobaxterm instead of Xming I was able to get Atom to show up in Windows remoted from my Ubuntu VMs, but still no joy with Ubuntu on Windows. If you want to try debugging this - I would suggest mobaxterm.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this? http://www.howtogeek.com/261449/how-to-install-linux-software-in-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell/ and http://www.howtogeek.com/261449/how-to-install-linux-software-in-windows-10s-ubuntu-bash-shell/

Your question is very interesting to me I've never heard of a piece of software that had packages for debian and redhat distros but not windows. (usually it's the other way around) I'm personally interested in solving this because it's so out of the ordinary to me yet very interesting especially with it being possible with windows bash and all. I'll update this answer with simplified instructions if and when I fully figure it out but wanted to post this in the meantime.

to comment on the other answer I had a feeling Linux subsystem support would be the problem based on what I googled. I remember once testing commands on a friends computer and discovering that not all standard bash commands have been implemented yet. I didn't want to say this before because I hoped it wasn't the case but in response to the asker it sounds like you might to wait until Microsoft gives more support to the Linux subsystem. I would've put this in a comment to that answer but I don't have the rep.

**Possible temporary solution**: in the meantime if you really want to use that editor you probably run a VM of a lightweight debian derivative like Lubuntu http://lubuntu.net/ I know that may not be ideal but wantedto mention it just in case.

Comment: I am trying to run an Ubuntu Server VM and use SSH X11 forwarding to get Atom to render into Xming on Windows but that is also proving problematic for different(?) reasons.

Comment: I don't know why it's still being problematic. The only thing I can think of to ask is what VM software are you using?

Comment: I am using VirtualBox.

Comment: not sure if this would help but maybe try using this instead? http://www.vmware.com/products/player/playerpro-evaluation.html

Answer (score 0):

Since Bash on Windows is beta, there are going to be some issues.  Googling, I found [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/758), which matches your error.  The thread says the shutdown syscall is not implemented.

Comment: I think this is an after-the-fact symptom of the problem, but I may be wrong.